# How to format date of datepicker Jquery?

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I want my datepicker to select date in this format : dd/mm/yyyy
This is my current code.

```
$(function () {
    var dateString = "10/06/1993"; // dd/mm/yyyy
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    $('.input-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date );
    $('.input-datepicker')
         .datepicker({format:'dd/mm/yyyy'})
         .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
          }
     );
});
```

Now, if I click at the input, datepicker is selected at 6 october instead of 10 June.

And when I alert(date), it shows this message " Wed Oct 06 1993 00:00:00 GMT ... ".

How can I make it select date by format dd/mm/yyyy?

Or is it possible to create new Date with format? (since new Date(dateString) has format like dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: It looks like your code is correct (at least it's the same as I use for format).
However, when you alert (date) you're alerting your 'new Date(dateString).
If you were to alert $('.input-datepicker').val() you should get the properly formatted date.

Comment: @PatDobson I alert( $('.input-datepicker').val() ) and it is also "10/01/1993" when I select 1 oct instead of "01/10/1993".

Comment: Try using 'dateString in this line: '$('.input-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date );' i.e. put raw text in instead of creating a new date object.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it using the UTC like:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(1993,05,10));
$('.input-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date );
```

Also pay attention on the month, to get june its not 6 but 5, the month starts with 0!

Answer (score 0):

you use this `var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();`
or more information here :

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing portion in your code. The property is **dateFormat** & NOT only **format** :

Here you go, try this:

```
$(function () {
    var dateString = "10/06/1993"; // dd/mm/yyyy
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    $('.input-datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date );
    $('.input-datepicker')
         .datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'})
         .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
          }
     );
});
```

Fiddle Link: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/f680fq9y/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".input-datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/geogeorge/2tqxjd2p/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="tejaseethal, tejaseethal537@gmail.com">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```